# Lazily instantiate dependencies using DI in iOS (Typhoon & Objection)

Tags: objective-c, dependency-injection, typhoon

I am a huge fan of dependency injection pattern but I am a little sceptical when it comes to following this pattern in mobile development and the main reason being memory allocation. I will briefly explain what my concern is:

I am using DI in my Objective-C based iOS project. I have used both Objection and Typhoon but could not find a way to lazily instantiate the dependencies (not talking specifically about Singletons). I get my dependencies injected even if the use case flow of the app does not require the object to be allocated. As soon as I call `injectDependencies:` method (Objection) or plist Integration (Typhoon) all the dependencies are injected. Although Objection site mentions it lazily loads everything but I didn't see a proof of that. Is there a way to lazy load the dependencies using these frameworks? For example, I want something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) MyClass *classObject;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Check at this point that classObject should be nil

    id str = classObject.myString;

    // As soon as the getter is called, the property is first instantiated and then returned a value.
}
```

Is DI meant to be this way? If yes then doesn't this pattern defies the memory allocation thumb rule for mobile (allocate only when you need it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typhoon founder here.

**Dependency Injection on Server Side Projects**

When we use Dependency Injection with server-side frameworks, the default scope is singleton. This makes sense, given that the server could be expected to serve any use-case at a given point in time.

**Dependency Injection on Mobile And Desktop**

In iOS we may have some background (singleton) components, however we're typically focusing on one use case at a time. Therefore, ***Typhoon introduces the unique `TyphoonScopeObjectGraph` as the default*** among its [scopes](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes).

With `TyphoonScopeObjectGraph` means that the relationship between dependencies are described, a Typhoon will create a shared instance *only while the object graph  is being solved*. This means you can wire-up a complex object graph using circular dependencies (delegate pattern) and so forth. Typhoon then hands this entire object graph to whatever will be using it, and releases ownership.

Normal Objective-C runtime rules apply from here - if the controller or whatever is using the built object-graph has a strong property, then the graph will be retained in memory as long as that view controller is.

In this way we can proceed from one object graph (use-case) to another, while preserving memory on resource constrained devices.

**Other Scopes**

Typhoon also includes the following additional scopes besides the default:

- `TyphoonScopeSingleton` - retained by the DI container. Use for background daemons and so forth.
- `TyphoonScopeLazySingleton` - like a regular singleton, but instantiation is delayed until the first time it is used. (I believe Objection singletons work like this).
- `TyphoonScopeWeakSingleton` - instantiated and shared as long as at least one object is retaining it, then destroyed. Will be re-instantiated the next time it is requested again.
- `TyphoonScopePrototype` - always creates a new instance, even during a single solve cycle.

**Proceeding from One Object Graph to Another:**

A typhoon built story board can load another object-graph, such as another view controller to proceed to a new use-case 'on-demand'. To do this we Typhoon as a factory class, and [inject the assembly itself](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself), optionally. We can then ask Typhoon to build an instance of the required class. If you wish you can back your assembly with a protocol, so that your class is not coupled directly to Typhoon.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jasper. To begin Typhoon actually defines the correct way of DI rather than Objection. But my main concern here is that there is a way to scope singletons as lazy singletons i.e. instantiation is delayed until first time used, but is there a way to set this scope to variables which are not singleton? Or TyphoonScopeObjectGraph lazily loads them?

Comment: TyphoonScopeLazySingleton delays until the first time used. TyphoonScopeObjectGraph means all will be free/discarded after your view controller (or whatever is using the object) is discarded. Only the recipes (dependency rules) for building the objects are retained, not the objects themselves.

Comment: Apologies if I am not making this clear. Lets assume a case where there is a dependency that would hardly be used in my use case. But since I need to inject it from assembly class using injectProperty method, this will for sure be allocated as soon as the ViewController is allocated and injectProperty method is called on it. I am concerned about such scenarios.

Comment: For that you can inject the assembly itself (https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself) and then resolve the very heavy object as needed. . you can also use this to proceed from one VC to another, if you're not using storyboards, which is the same kind of thing.

Comment: Ah, I get your point now. Sounds perfect!. Please give me a little more time to analyse couple of my queries and findings. I might bother you again before accepting the answer.

Comment: Take your time - thanks for your interest in Typhoon

Comment: One last question. I noticed that all the Typhoon definitions in Assembly classes (inherited from TyphoonAssembly) are called initially even before the call of AppDelegate. Though I also noticed that this does not affect the memory allocation. Could you please briefly explain, why all the definitions of the entire application are called initially?

Comment: Can you please ask a new question, as SO discourages long discussions in comments. Have a read of this first: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/TyphoonAssembly . . . and then proceed if still not clear.